# The opposite of "communication on social media"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for an expression for interpersonal communication which happens *in the real life* (for example, conversations at dinner table) as opposed to that which happens on the social media. The one that  I sense is probably close is **offline communication**, but I'm unsure about it.

Which expression best fills the following blank?

> Due to addiction to social media and lack of ____ , many people become unable to socialise with others offline.

Comment: So when my wife says *What do you fancy for dinner tonight?*, that constitutes *an off-line communication* does it?

Comment: I've always *talked* to people be it online or offline. If you want to specify the difference than say *lack of conversation skills* AKA the [*art of conversation*](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22art+of+conversation%22)

Comment: It's called "real communication", or perhaps "conversation".  If the parties are in physical proximity of each other (vs over the phone) then it's "face-to-face communication".

Comment: communication in real life, of course.

Comment: @Lambie yeah of course! How could I have missed this one lol

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use some variant of the phrase "unmediated _____".

"Social media" refers to "media" the plural of "medium" which refers to something that is in between or in the middle (< Latin "medius").  You are asking for the opposite of that, which could be referred to as *unmediated* communication or *unmediated* social interaction.

Comment: I just googled it and it seemed to be exactly what I was looking for. Cheers!

Comment: People won't necessarily know what is intended by **unmediated**,  since it is used in other contexts, not unless you explain it in the text, in which case you don't need this jargon.

Answer (score 11):

You could consider using [**face-to-face communication**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Face-to-face_interaction) or **face-to-face discourse**:

> Face-to-face interaction (less often, **face-to-face communication** or
>   **face-to-face discourse**) is a concept in sociology, linguistics, media
>   and communication studies describing social interaction carried out
>   **without any mediating technology**.

[Wikipedia]

Comment: What's wrong with the word *speaking*, (or, at most *verbal conversation*) that you need to change it into *face-to-face interaction*? It sounds like the janitor's handbook which referred to *translocation of dirt*, which it was pointed out meant *sweeping up*. Why can't you use the English you were born with? So ***speaking*** is *a concept in sociology, linguistics, media, and communication studies describing social interaction carried out without any mediating technology*, is it? I shall have to remember that.

Comment: @WS2 Can't you speak or have verbal conversation over Skype?

Comment: Thanks for your source. By the way, will "offline communication" do? And will "online communication" be proper to use to describe communication on social media?

Comment: You can also have it over the telephone. But we have managed since the days of Alexander Graham Bell without a need to talk about *face-to-face interaction*, - or at least I have.

Comment: @Vim I shall have to retire for a while. I need to have some *offline communication* with my wife about what we are doing this afternoon.

Comment: @WS2 As the definition explains, it is the term for communication that doesn't involve any mediating technology.

Comment: @Rathony Like bawling at the dog?

Comment: @Vim I am not a communication expert, but there is a problem with off-line communication. If you consider it as the exact opposite of on-line communication, it could include the phone conversation that doesn't involve the internet. Or it could include other communication methods that could be delivered off-line such as newspaper. I think off-line communication could have bigger meaning than face-to-face communication.

Comment: @Rathony Smoke signals?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that the word you're looking for is just "direct". "lack of direct communication" makes perfect sense (and strikes me, for one, as expressing the intent much more...directly than "unmediated").

Comment: Wow. Honestly *direct* was the very first choice to pop in to my mind but then I thought maybe it was too broad (why cannot online communication count as direct communication? Or, what is *indirect* communication? I wonder)

Comment: "Personal" and "direct" seem to cover the territory without resorting to esoterica. +1

Comment: @Vim: at least to me, "indirect" would mean "via some sort of mediator"--such as social media.

Answer (score 1):

Lack of **in-person** communication.

When we say that a meeting or a conversation was "in person" it means the individuals were there "in the flesh". Physically present at the same place at the same time.

Comment: It is interesting that this answer seems rather obvious now, but did not occur to anybody in 2016, when the question was asked. I suspect that this is because the use of *in-person* increased greatly in the period of easing various Covid-related restrictions.

Comment: It is the obvious idiomatic choice but I don't think it has to do with Covid restrictions being released. I've been using "in person" for decades and would have answered this question the same way twenty years ago.

Answer (score -1):

Sherry Turkle, author of "Alone Together: Why we Expect more from Technology and Less from Each other" calls it real-time conversation.

Comment: *Real time* (unless stipulatively defined otherwise for a particular context) is likely to be understood to mean only that there is no significant delay between the conversational moves, not that the communication is not electronically mediated. An online 'chat' in which the participants are logged in simultaneously and respond to each other without a delay can be regarded as real-time conversation.